# last order filtered with dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data table with thousands of rows. This data table contains the order code, order information created for each inventory. Each inventory can have more than one order, which is what is challenging me. I want to do counting on the last order of each inventory in certain criteria. how can I do it with dax.

I tried using the LASTDATE and MAX functions within the CALCULATE function, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is named "Orders" and contains columns "InventoryCode", "OrderCode", "OrderDate", and "CriteriaColumn" (the column based on which you want to apply the criteria), follow these steps:

Step 1: Create a calculated column to rank the orders within each inventory based on the order date.

```
RankColumn = 
RANKX(
    FILTER(Orders, Orders[InventoryCode] = EARLIER(Orders[InventoryCode])),
    Orders[OrderDate],
    ,
    ASC,
    Dense
)
```

Step 2: Create a measure to count the last order based on the criteria.

```
LastOrderCount = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(Orders[OrderCode]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Orders),
        Orders[RankColumn] = CALCULATE(MAX(Orders[RankColumn]), ALLEXCEPT(Orders, Orders[InventoryCode])),
        Orders[CriteriaColumn] = [DesiredCriteria]  // Replace [DesiredCriteria] with your actual criteria
    )
)
```

In this example, the "RankColumn" calculated column assigns a rank to each order within the same inventory based on the order date. The "LastOrderCount" measure uses CALCULATE and FILTER to count the number of orders that meet the desired criteria and have the maximum rank within each inventory.

Remember to replace [DesiredCriteria] with the actual criteria you want to use for counting the orders.

Please note that creating calculated columns and measures can affect the performance of your Power BI report, especially when dealing with large datasets. Make sure to test and optimize your calculations as needed.

Comment: I will try as soon as possible and write the result